# The intersection of a class of ordinals belongs to that class

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

In Jech's *Set Theory* he claims (p. 20, new millennium edition):

> If $C$ is a nonempty class of ordinals, then $\cap C$ is an ordinal, $\cap C \in C$ and $\cap C = \inf C$

Jech does not give a proof, stating that it is routine. I'm finding it difficult to prove that $\cap C \in C$ if $C$ is a proper class.

I know how to do this if $C$ is a set, but if $C$ is a proper class I see no way except by induction over all first-order formulae. Am I right in thinking this, or is there a more direct method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick some element $c$ of $C$. Because the ordinals are totally ordered by inclusion, the intersection over the *non-empty set* $(c+1)\cap C$ is the same as the intersection over the class $C$. Now apply the set version and you're done.